# jasmine-node done is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine-node

Have been trying a simple async test. Installed jasmine-node `npm install -g jasmine-node` then wrote a simple module and test.

Simple module.

```
// weather.js
exports.get = function(city, callback) {
    callback(city);
};
```

and a test suite.

```
// weather-spec.js
var list = require("../modules/weather");

describe("Weather Forecast", function(data) {
    it('should get weather for London,UK', function() {
        list.get('London,UK', function(data) {
            expect(data).toEqual('London,UK');
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

I get the error:

```
Stacktrace:
    ReferenceError: done is not defined
```

Given the simple example I can't see where I am going wrong. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`done` is the first argument passed to `it`:

```
it('should get weather for London,UK', function(done) {
    list.get('London,UK', function(data) {
        expect(data).toEqual('London,UK');
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

```
describe("Weather Forecast", function(data) {
    it('should get weather for London,UK', function(done) {
        list.get('London,UK', function(data) {
            expect(data).toEqual('London,UK');
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Make sure you pass in `done` in `it`'s callback.